# MySQL Merge Queries on same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do is this

I have id numbers and criteria column with either 0 or 1 value. I want to get the percentages for those.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table; /* ALL COUNT */
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE criteria='1' /* pass count */ 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE criteira='0' /* fail count */
```

Thats the very basic of it but not what I am trying to do. I need the pass and fail percentages. How do I get that ?

Comment: Can criteria be anything besides 1 or 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `COUNT()` and `SUM()` with condition also using aggregate functions without grouping then will result in one row ,sum with condition will return as boolean so if conditon matches it results as true and will work as count

```
SELECT COUNT(id) `all`
,SUM(criteria='1') `pass`
,SUM(criteria='0') `fail`
FROM `table`
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it helps! Although this does not give me percentages, this is almost what I need. I was hoping to leverage MySQL to get the percentages for pass and fail and find a way to do that without querying for the `all` count more than once. I can do that with PHP no no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as the other post, but I think the use of `IF` is inescapable!

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
    , SUM(IF(criteria='1', 1, 0)) AS `pass`
    , SUM(IF(criteria='0', 1, 0)) AS `fail`
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7d5af/9)

```
SELECT
ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN CRITERIA = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(1)) * 100, 2) AS PASS_PCT,
ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN CRITERIA = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(1)) * 100, 2) AS FAIL_PCT
FROM SAMPLE
```